# paste0() adds an escape forward backslash in call to API?

Tags: r, curl, httr, notion-api

I need to dynamically make a call to an API using the following format:

```
 auth_secret <- paste0("Bearer ", secret)

  headers = c(
    `Authorization` = auth_secret,
    `Notion-Version` = '2022-02-22',
    `Content-Type` = 'application/json' )

  res <- httr::PATCH(url = paste0('https://api.notion.com/v1/pages/', id),
                     httr::add_headers(.headers = headers),
                     body = payload,
                     encode = "json")
  d <- httr::content(res)
```

This payload works:

```
payload <- "{\"properties\":{\"Project\":{\"relation\":[{\"id\":\"1d148a9e-783d-47a7-b3e8-2d9c34210355\"}]}}}"
```

But if I want to create it dynamically, using a paste0 (so it is inside of a function), I get some backslashes added before and after:

```
payload <- paste0('"{\"properties\":{\"',property_name,'\":{\"relation\":[{\"id\":\"',value,'\"}]}}}"')

print(payload) 

"\"{\"properties\":{\"%7CAK%5E\":{\"relation\":[{\"id\":\"8cb9519e72ca4bbe9e0448807acb8e10\"}]}}}\""
```

I presume this is due to some weird escape character being added but have run out of ideas. I've added two \ and have gotten same issue. Call fails as JSON is not passed correctly. Is there a workaround?

Comment: There are no backslashes being added. There are double quotes being added because you are putting them there. You have double quotes inside the single quotes when you write `paste0('"{`. Just remove the outer single quotes and you should get the result your want. (The backslash is indeed just an escape character signifying that the following character is a literal double quote character)

Comment: It would be easier if you created your payload as a list and let `httr` take care of encoding to a JSON string for you. Also to see what strings look like without escaping, be sure to `cat()` their value rather than `print()`. If you print to the console, certain characters as escaped but that's purely a visual change and doesn't reflect what's actually in the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is obviously something to do with the fact that `paste0` is escaping even the double quotes you do not want to escape.

No doubt someone is aware of the details. However, when I get weird stuff with `paste0`, I just use `sprintf`, which seems to work in this case:

```r
property_name = "Projects"
value = "1d148a9e-783d-47a7-b3e8-2d9c34210355"
payload  <- sprintf(
    "{\"properties\":{\"%s\":{\"relation\":[{\"id\":\"%s\"}]}}}",
    property_name, value
)
print(payload)
# [1] "{\"properties\":{\"Projects\":{\"relation\":[{\"id\":\"1d148a9e-783d-47a7-b3e8-2d9c34210355\"}]}}}"
```

Comment: weird! but this did it! thanks!